# Making the keyboard eject switch work

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, system-calls

I am using Linux.My keyboard switch for ejecting the CDROM does not work though it displays an eject button on the screen. I need to make it work. I know ejecting a cdrom using system call is as simple as

```
ioctl(cdromfd,CDROMEJECT,0)
```

But I don't know how to connect the an executable that contains the above system call and the event of pressing the eject key? Or shall I rely on kernel level? If then how?

Comment: Read the comment of the following question. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61319/making-the-keyboard-eject-switch-work

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
system ("eject");
```

or

```
fp = popen("eject", "r");
close(fp);
```

Comment: Tell me how to connect it with the button. I know how to eject it using commands and programs.

Comment: in the method related to your button click  just call one of the suggested C code

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure e.g. your desktop environment to catch the key, and call the [`eject`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/eject) command for the correct device. No programming needed.

To find out the key-code, use e.g. the [`xev`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xev) command.

If you don't want the <kbd>Eject</kbd> key to be available generally, but only in a program you made, you have to add a check for keyboard events in your event loop and check for the keycode you got from `xev`.